# Call a method on componentWillReceiveProps based on previous path url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What I am trying to achieve is the call a method based on previous path url (I am using react-router).

Previous path URL looks like

`http://www.website.com/signin?f=world-news&join=true&nextPath=%2Ff%2Fworld-news`

and on successful sign in user is redirected to

`http://www.website.com/f/world-news`

Now, when my component is mounted and I see the new URL, I would like to trigger a method, but only if the user is signed in from the previous url that I specified in my question. The unique string in the previous URL is `&join=true`. How can I call a method in `componentWillReceiveProps` when the previous path contains `&join=true`

example pseudo code looks like

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from "react";
import MyComponentView from "./view";

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if ( // prevoius path logic check ) {
            this.props.myMethod(); // Calling the method over here
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyComponentView {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Update:  Adding the code with redirect functionality

```
_getCurrentPathName() {
        let path = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
        if (path === "/") {
            return undefined;
        }
        return path;
    }

transitionToSigninAndAutoJoin(query) {
    const q = Object.assign({}, query, {
        f: this.props.params.slug,
        nextPath: this._getCurrentPathName(),
        join: true
    });

    this.transitionTo({ pathname: "/signin", query: q });
}
```

In summary, when I click a button in my component it checks whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in I am calling the method `myMethod()` as mention in the original code sample.

If not, I am redirecting the user to sign-in page (calling `transitionToSigninAndAutoJoin`), which take the current path and and redirects to signin path. For e.g. if my current path name is `http://www.website.com/f/world-news` and the user is not logged in, the new redirection url looks like `http://www.website.com/signin?f=world-news&join=true&nextPath=%2Ff%2Fworld-news`

Upon sucessful signin user is redirected back to `http://www.website.com/f/world-news`, but now I want to call `myMethod()` automatically when the component is mountedd. However, `myMethod()` should only be called automatically when the previous url contains `&join=true`

Comment: Are you using any kind of flux or local data storage solution?

Comment: I am not using local data storage. When it comes about flux I am using redux

Comment: If the redirect is done using `react-router` then you should be able to store the previous path in the reducer. Are you using `react-router` for this redirect?

Comment: @HussienK I have added the redirect code and added additional information describing what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Is your redirect functionality in Redux action? Because you could store the previous url by dispatching an action to save it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is using window window.location.pathname and adding the current slug + current path name as nextPath. So, once user is signed in he/she is rediected to the next path (in this case is it is the path user came from)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the previous URL, you can add a `state` object to the [location descriptor](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v3.2.1/docs/Location.md) when you are redirecting.

```
function redirectAfterSignin() {
  const {
    nextPath,
    join = false
  } = this.props.location.query

  this.router.push({
    pathname: nextPath,
    state: { join }
  })
}
```

Then in your other component, you will just need to check the `location.state` prop to determine the `join` value.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location.state.join) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should I define and call `redirectAfterSignin`?

Comment: You should use the code inside of that function wherever you are currently redirecting to `nextPath` from.